# What is the following regex doing (?-mix:{0})

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking at this code, and it is formatting all regular expressions using this function:

```
string.Format("(?-mix:{0})", regex);
```

What exactly does `(?-mix:{0})` mean?  (I know the `{0}` is a placeholder).

Here is the code:

https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/blob/master/src/DotLiquid/Liquid.cs#L36
https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/blob/master/src/DotLiquid/Util/R.cs#L12

```
public static string Q(string regex)
        {
            return string.Format("(?-mix:{0})", regex);
        }


public static class Liquid
    {
        internal static readonly ResourceManager ResourceManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(DotLiquid.Properties.Resources));

        public static readonly string FilterSeparator = R.Q(@"\|");
        public static readonly string ArgumentSeparator = R.Q(@",");
        public static readonly string FilterArgumentSeparator = R.Q(@":");
        public static readonly string VariableAttributeSeparator = R.Q(@".");
        public static readonly string TagStart = R.Q(@"\{\%");
        public static readonly string TagEnd = R.Q(@"\%\}");
        public static readonly string VariableSignature = R.Q(@"\(?[\w\-\.\[\]]\)?");
        public static readonly string VariableSegment = R.Q(@"[\w\-]");
        public static readonly string VariableStart = R.Q(@"\{\{");
        public static readonly string VariableEnd = R.Q(@"\}\}");
        public static readonly string VariableIncompleteEnd = R.Q(@"\}\}?");
        public static readonly string QuotedString = R.Q(@"""[^""]*""|'[^']*'");
        public static readonly string QuotedFragment = string.Format(R.Q(@"{0}|(?:[^\s,\|'""]|{0})+"), QuotedString);
        public static readonly string QuotedAssignFragment = string.Format(R.Q(@"{0}|(?:[^\s\|'""]|{0})+"), QuotedString);
        public static readonly string StrictQuotedFragment = R.Q(@"""[^""]+""|'[^']+'|[^\s\|\:\,]+");
        public static readonly string FirstFilterArgument = string.Format(R.Q(@"{0}(?:{1})"), FilterArgumentSeparator, StrictQuotedFragment);
        public static readonly string OtherFilterArgument = string.Format(R.Q(@"{0}(?:{1})"), ArgumentSeparator, StrictQuotedFragment);
        public static readonly string SpacelessFilter = string.Format(R.Q(@"^(?:'[^']+'|""[^""]+""|[^'""])*{0}(?:{1})(?:{2}(?:{3})*)?"), FilterSeparator, StrictQuotedFragment, FirstFilterArgument, OtherFilterArgument);
        public static readonly string Expression = string.Format(R.Q(@"(?:{0}(?:{1})*)"), QuotedFragment, SpacelessFilter);
        public static readonly string TagAttributes = string.Format(R.Q(@"(\w+)\s*\:\s*({0})"), QuotedFragment);
        public static readonly string AnyStartingTag = R.Q(@"\{\{|\{\%");
        public static readonly string PartialTemplateParser = string.Format(R.Q(@"{0}.*?{1}|{2}.*?{3}"), TagStart, TagEnd, VariableStart, VariableIncompleteEnd);
        public static readonly string TemplateParser = string.Format(R.Q(@"({0}|{1})"), PartialTemplateParser, AnyStartingTag);
        public static readonly string VariableParser = string.Format(R.Q(@"\[[^\]]+\]|{0}+\??"), VariableSegment);
        public static readonly string LiteralShorthand = R.Q(@"^(?:\{\{\{\s?)(.*?)(?:\s*\}\}\})$");
        public static readonly string CommentShorthand = R.Q(@"^(?:\{\s?\#\s?)(.*?)(?:\s*\#\s?\})$");
```

Comment: What is the resulting string used for?

Comment: It is used to pass into a Regex.Match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a regular expression - it is a format string, as this is a call to `string.Format` .

This simply formats the string and places the value of the `regex` variable (or rather the result of calling `ToString()` on it) in place of the `{0}`.

The result is the string `"(?-mix:<whatever regex.ToString() is>)"`.

This string *looks* like it could be a regular expression, and would turn off a few modifiers (so this would be case sensitive, ^ and $ match start and end of line only and free spacing mode is off). See [Regular Expression Advanced Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) on [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

So the above would match `regex` with those options off.

Comment: My question is about the regex, it is basically wrapping all regexes used using this String.Format, so I am askign what the ?-mix: part is doing.

Comment: @user1361315 - The code you posted was confusing the matter, as there is no use of `Regex`. However, I have updated the answer with some detail.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a little bit late, but just in case you didn't find out what it means:

Regular expressions defines a capturing group between `(` and `)`. When you need grouping, but a non-capturing one, you will write the expression between `(?:` and `)`. And some regex processors accepts on/off flags between `?` and `:` of non-capturing group. So there goes the "mixing" stuff, which actually means turn off some flags about the group, delimited with a `-` sign (turn the flag off):

- `m modifier off`: -multi-line, ^ and $ match not only begin/end of line
- `i modifier off`: -insensitive, case sensitive match
- `x modifier off`: -extended, whitespaces in pattern are literal whitespaces

So, it becomes `(?-mix:` ... `)` when you turn them off. It's the same thing with `(?-ixm:` ... `)` or in any other order.

Anyway, I don't think Regex class of .NET cares about those flags, better check it later. It's migrated from original ruby source of liquid engine.

Comment: Well, .NET cares and supports this notation, `(?imnsx-imnsx: subexpression)`. Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx